# Background Recyclerview shows incorrectly after changing to Light/ Dark theme from Android App

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, background, light, android-dark-theme

Anyone can help me?
I'm developing the Light and Dark theme function in the android app, everything goes fine, but the background of Recyclerview shows incorrectly.

The root background of xml file is White color and I didn't set background for recyclerview in xml. However, after changing from Light to Dark or Dark to Right=> background of recyclerview automatically change to a strange color(this color didn't see in my color.xml resource). I tried to set background of Recyclerview to @null or transparent in code and xml file as well but the background of recyclerview didn't remove that strange color.

So anyone knows exactly the reason why, please help me and much appreciated. Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqFuH.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8F3P.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using the `DayNight` Theme. If so you should have to `themes.xml` folder in `res`, one is called as mentioned and the other is with the extension `(night)`. There you can define a color in both `xml` files. It has the same name but different color values like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffff</item> <!-- you normally shouldn't hardcode color -->
</style>
```

The same for your folder `(night)`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item> <!-- you normally shouldn't hardcode color -->
</style>
```

The idea is to have one attribute name that contains 2 colors and takes the correct one if needed. For futher understanding I suggest to take a look at this [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) to get more familiar with Themes and Styles. Now you set up your `Day` and `Night` files properly, you can implement it by using it in your `recyclerView` as follows:

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
```

Another tip is to make custom colors in multiple colors.xml files to make them for more unique use. In this case `colorPrimaryDark` effect your whole app. It is also suggested to modify layouts and the visuals of `widgets` to take effect only on those. (e.x. your `recyclerView`). In my app I used `colorPrimaryDark` for all Background (that should be same for more clean design). I think you get the keypoint. Take a look around the net and this forum and you will find your final design strategy. Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, I follow your instructions but it didn't work.